# Enumerate table rows by diff between timestamps

Tags: sql

I've got the following ordered by user_id, timestamp table:

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1661919816 |
| 1000 | 1661919861 |
| 1001 | 1661919816 |

I need to enumerate this table with session id by the following rules:

1. When diff between two timestamps is less than 1 minute, then it is the same session
2. When diff is more than 1 minute, then it is previous session_id + 1
3. When user_id changes, so does session_id (again previous session_id + 1)

So in my case I want something like this:

| user_id | timestamp | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1661919816 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1661919861 | 1 |
| 1001 | 1661919816 | 2 |

I need something like `dense_rank()`, however I don't know how to apply it to diff between two timestamps

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `LAG` window function to parse the previous `user_id` and `timestamp` values, then you can check if the `user_id` value has changed, or if it is the same, check if the `timestamp` difference is greater than 1 minute (60 seconds). You can then use the `SUM` window function to calculate the value of `session_id`.

Such a query might look like this

```
SELECT 
    user_id,
    timestamp,
    SUM(flag) OVER (ORDER BY user_id, timestamp) session_id
FROM (    
SELECT
    *,
    CASE WHEN user_id = LAG(user_id) OVER (ORDER BY user_id, timestamp)
              AND timestamp - LAG(timestamp, 1, 0) OVER (ORDER BY user_id, timestamp) < 60
         THEN 0 -- user_id is not changed and timestamp difference is smaller than 1 minute, do not increment session_id
         ELSE 1 -- increment session_id since user_id is changed or timestamp difference is greater than 1 minute
    END flag
FROM sessions
) flags
```

For your sample data, query output

| user_id | timestamp | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1661919816 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1661919861 | 1 |
| 1001 | 1661919816 | 2 |

For extended sample data like this

| user_id | timestamp |
| --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1661919816 |
| 1000 | 1661919861 |
| 1000 | 1661919871 |
| 1000 | 1661919931 |
| 1001 | 1661919816 |
| 1001 | 1661919896 |
| 1001 | 1661919906 |

query output

| user_id | timestamp | session_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1000 | 1661919816 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1661919861 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1661919871 | 1 |
| 1000 | 1661919931 | 2 |
| 1001 | 1661919816 | 3 |
| 1001 | 1661919896 | 4 |
| 1001 | 1661919906 | 4 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=1ca17ae88360f8237634bb5a32d02cf1)*